# Replicate part of a table in the same database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a large table (several million rows) in a MySQL (version 5.0) database that has data inserted into it at a very frequent rate.

There are also less frequent select statements done against the database that only required the latest data (i.e. the newest 10000 rows), is there a way to create a table that would keep a copy of data from the main table and would dynamically add new rows whenever a new row was added to the main table (I can delete the old data periodically so that's not too much of an issue) without causing much of an impact to the main table.

If possible I would also like to Index rows in the 2nd table slightly differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

You'll need three triggers on the large table:

- AFTER INSERT, for each row you'll need to copy the new row into the smaller table and delete the oldest row from the smaller table
- AFTER UPDATE, for each row you'll need to check whether that row is in the smaller table and if it is, make the same updates to it
- AFTER DELETE, for each row you'll need to check whether that row is in the smaller table and if it is, remove it.

For example:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert AFTER INSERT ON big_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE small_table_rows INTEGER;
    INSERT INTO small_table (field1, field2) VALUES (NEW.field1, NEW.field2);
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO small_table_rows FROM small_table;
    IF small_table_rows > 10000 THEN
        DELETE FROM small_table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
    END IF
END;//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_update AFTER UPDATE ON big_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE small_table
    SET field1 = NEW.field1, field2 = NEW.field2
    WHERE small_table.id = NEW.id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_delete AFTER DELETE ON big_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM small_table WHERE small_table.id = OLD.id;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

It's fairly straightforward, though the triggers can get unwieldy if the tables have a lot of columns.  You may want to consider the performance characteristics of MyISAM vs InnoDB; InnoDB may offer better overall performance depending on what sorts of queries you are running.

You don't want to use views; views in MySQL are not materialized, so you won't generally get any performance benefit (which is what it sounds like you want) and you won't be able to index the view differently from the table(s) on which the view is based.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sri Kumar and Indutiomarus.

Triggers seem like the best way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VIEWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) that will get updated if the parent gets updated or you can use 
[TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)